# Elegant Dataframe Operations in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

What is the most pythonic/elegant way to approach the following problem?

I have a dataframe  df:

```
Group    Start Date    End Date
A         8/15/2017     8/30/2017
B         8/20/2017      NaT
C         8/07/2017     8/14/2017
A         9/07/2017      NaT
```

`Group` is a string and `Start Date` and `End Date` are datetimes

I need to perform some operations with the Groups that have no `End Date` each day.  If these operations dictate that the group's end date is on that day, I replace the `NaT` with the date.

The only way I can figure out doing this is as follows:

```
import pandas as pd

df_closed = df[pd.notnull(df['End_Date'])]
df_open = df[pd.isnull(df['End_Date'])]
```

Which gives me:

```
df_closed

Group    Start Date    End Date
A         8/15/2017     8/30/2017
C         8/07/2017     8/14/2017
```

and:

```
df_open

Group    Start Date    End Date
B         8/20/2017      NaT
A         9/07/2017      NaT
```

Then I perform my operations.  If, say, I determine that Group A's End Date should be 'today' (let's say 'today' is 9/10/2017), I do

```
df_open.loc['A','End Date'] = 9/10/2017
```

so I have the following:

```
df_open

Group    Start Date    End Date
B         8/20/2017      NaT
A         9/07/2017    9/10/2017
```

At the end of these operations I want my original dataframe to show all original rows but with updated `end dates`.  so I do the following:

```
df = df_closed.append(df_open)
```

which gives me:

```
Group    Start Date    End Date
A         8/15/2017     8/30/2017
B         8/20/2017      NaT
C         8/07/2017     8/14/2017
A         9/07/2017     9/10/2017
```

This gets the job done but I have to think there is a less 'clunky' way to do this.

Insights?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can `df.loc[(df['Group'] == 'A') & df['End Date'].isnull(), 'End Date'] = today`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can locate null values and return them for assignment in the same step:

```
df.loc[df['End Date'].isnull(), 'End Date'] = <<val>>
```

If you need to locate the group as well:

```
df.loc[(df['End Date'].isnull()) & (df['Group']==<<group>>), 'End Date'] = <<val>>
```

This way you can keep everything in the same dataframe, which is less messy than separating your df and re-merging.